# How to link to specific id_contact in customer service in Pretsashop 1.5?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

with Prestashop 1.4, i used to create a link to specific id_contact in customer service like this :

> http://www.my-website.com/contact-us?id_contact=1

But it doesn’t work any more with Prestashop 1.5.

Do you know a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because in the default theme the line for display options in contact list select is like this :
`<option value="{$contact.id_contact|intval}" {if isset($smarty.post.id_contact) && $smarty.post.id_contact == $contact.id_contact}selected="selected"{/if}>`

If you replace the $smarty.post by $smarty.get, I think it can works with something like this :
`<option value="{$contact.id_contact|intval}" {if isset($smarty.get.id_contact) && $smarty.get.id_contact == $contact.id_contact}selected="selected"{/if}>`

Or if you want you can replace by $smarty.request so it can works with POST and GET methods.

Comment: I understand. I works now. Do you know why it has changed on 1.5 ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel No idea why did it change. But this "feature" depends on the theme so it's not a big change but just a "configuration".